# How do I resolve having a M:N relationship in my Crow's Foot Model? Am I on the right track?

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation, visio

I am very much a beginner and taking a class on databases. My assignment involves using Crow's Foot notation to represent the following tables:

[image]

This is my design for it so far. I am nowhere near done but am I at least on the right track? I would have to use a composite entity to resolve the M:N relationships shown with these tables, right?

(Those M:N relationships being Employee to Plan and Benefit to Plan)

[image]

Please be forgiving of my work haha.

I really appreciate all of the help and insight!

Hope you all have a good one wherever you are!

Comment: i can't see why do oyu have Benefit and Sign_UP which is a bridge btable between Plan and Employee, and two identical tables doesn't make any sense

Comment: Hi. Homework questions are generally acceptable here as long as they show effort and don't reduce to "what did your teacher say / did you read the textbook." Don't be surprised or offended, though, if this question gets closed; it's unlikely to add long-term value to the site's corpus.

Comment: Very much understandable in this case. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where SIGN UP came in. Maybe there's more to your assignment than you describe in the question? No matter.

The rest looks good as far as it goes. BENEFIT has a column called EMP_ID. You may want to have a good think about that one.

As for the M:N. What columns would it have? Does that look like anything that exists already?

Answer (score 0):

I see where I went wrong as far as the Benefit column. Thank you for pointing that out. Really, thank you for taking the time to answer my question as you have. Going back over the assignment, my notes mention that usually M: N relationships are not directly supported in a relational environment, so I was trying to resolve that with the composite entity of SIGN UP. However looking at it with fresh eyes, I may have to re-think the direction. Good to know I am generally on the right track though.Thank you again very much!